# Vim color scheme not being applied

Tags: vim, colors, vimrc

I am installing [this](https://github.com/dracula/vim) theme using [these](https://draculatheme.com/vim/) instructions.

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr 08 2016 11:38:28)
Included patches: 1-1689
```

Here is my `~/.vim/colors`:

```
xxx@xxx:~/.vim/colors$ ll
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 j4x j4x 8401 Jun  3 17:17 dracula.vim
```

Here is my `/etc/vim/vimrc`:

```
" All system-wide defaults are set in $VIMRUNTIME/debian.vim and sourced by
" the call to :runtime you can find below.  If you wish to change any of those
" settings, you should do it in this file (/etc/vim/vimrc), since debian.vim
" will be overwritten everytime an upgrade of the vim packages is performed.
" It is recommended to make changes after sourcing debian.vim since it alters
" the value of the 'compatible' option.

" This line should not be removed as it ensures that various options are
" properly set to work with the Vim-related packages available in Debian.
runtime! debian.vim

" Uncomment the next line to make Vim more Vi-compatible
" NOTE: debian.vim sets 'nocompatible'.  Setting 'compatible' changes numerous
" options, so any other options should be set AFTER setting 'compatible'.
"set compatible

" Vim5 and later versions support syntax highlighting. Uncommenting the next
" line enables syntax highlighting by default.
if has("syntax")
  syntax on
endif

syntax on
color dracula

" If using a dark background within the editing area and syntax highlighting
" turn on this option as well
"set background=dark

" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when
" reopening a file
"if has("autocmd")
"  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
"endif

" Uncomment the following to have Vim load indentation rules and plugins
" according to the detected filetype.
if has("autocmd")
  filetype plugin indent on
endif

" The following are commented out as they cause vim to behave a lot
" differently from regular Vi. They are highly recommended though.
"set showcmd        " Show (partial) command in status line.
"set showmatch      " Show matching brackets.
"set ignorecase     " Do case insensitive matching
"set smartcase      " Do smart case matching
"set incsearch      " Incremental search
"set autowrite      " Automatically save before commands like :next and :make
"set hidden     " Hide buffers when they are abandoned
"set mouse=a        " Enable mouse usage (all modes)

" Source a global configuration file if available
if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use 'colorscheme' rather than 'color' in your vimrc and place it in your local vimrc file (~/.vimrc). Also, you are testing this on python files and vim may need some settings to correctly recognise them.

Try adding the following lines to ~/.vimrc:

```
syntax on
colorscheme dracula
filetype indent plugin on
```

Comment: Didn't work either.

Comment: I notice you're amending the global vimrc file. Have you tried putting the colorscheme in the vimrc in your home directory ~/.vimrc ?

Comment: ~/.vimrc is a (hidden) file in your home directory, into which you should place your user-specific vim settings. This is where I set my colorscheme, (which is set using the files in the directory ~/.vim/colors).  I'm surprised you don't already have this file but you should create it if you do not.

Comment: I tried moving the `vimrc` file to `~/.vimrc` and I also tried creating a directory called `~/.vimrc` and placing the `vimrc` file in there but neither worked.

Comment: Keep /etc/vim/vimrc where it is (commenting out or removing 'color dracula') and create a file ~/.vimrc which only contains 'colorscheme dracula'. I assume you're restarting vim each time you test your configuration changes.

Comment: Try [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vim#Configuration) website for more information

Comment: There may be a template vimrc available in /usr/share/vim/vimrc. You can copy this to your home directory (cp /usr/share/vim/vimrc ~/.vimrc) if you don't have one already and then edit it to include your colorscheme.

Comment: I removed the `color dracula` from my `/etc/vim/vimrc` and created a file `~/.vimrc` which only contains `colorscheme dracula`. Unfortunately it still isn't working.

Comment: When you say it isn't working, how are you testing it?

Comment: Opening a python file and checking the syntax highlighting. At the moment there is no highlighting.

Comment: If you type :colorscheme within vim what is showing?

Comment: It says `dracula`

Comment: So the colorscheme *is* loaded. I suspect vim doesn't recognise it as a python file. You might want to look at [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Vim) page for some suggestions about handling python files in vim.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40831/discussion-between-chris-elston-and-proletariat).

Comment: Adding `syntax on` before the colorscheme option did the trick for me. The `filetype ...` options were already set further up in the file due to it being required by Vundle. HTH